# Python Multiple decorators and calling functions

Tags: python, flask, decorator, bad-request

This question could be a simple question.

I have two python decorators having functions inside them as follows:

```
@app.route('/insertsql', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def insertsql():

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
```

I want to use the `login()` function inside the `insertsql()` function. Is that possible ? When I try it I get this error

> Bad Request The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server
>   could not understand.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: That should be possible out of the box (even though it smells like a bad design). I've just had a quick look at flask' source code and found that `@app.route` decorator does not change the underlying function (it just registers it). I.e. the error you receive is not related to decorators themselves. The problem must be somewhere else. Show us both the server code and how you call it.

Comment: I'm trying to handle the exception if the username is empty ( due to a refresh or something)
@app.route('/insertsql', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def insertsql():
    if not username:
        login()
While the other decorator contains the login function that the users see when they login in the very first time to use my system

Comment: 99% of bugs are in code, not in the concept how it should work. Don't tell me what it does, show me full code. Or even better: minimal working example to reproduce the error. And show me how exactly you make the http request from the client's side. It might be something wrong with the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways to approach this. If you want to ensure the user is logged in before running that action you could use a decorator.

```
@auth.login_required
def before_request():
```

However, it could be you are really just trying to do two things within one route. How I like to handle this is by breaking up Flask apps into different components. Routes, Controllers and Models. This way a route can call multiple controller actions, where that logic isn't tightly coupled to your route and can be easily re-used.

#### Project Structure:

`├── app.py
├── config.py
├── controllers
│   └── cases.py
├── manage.py
├── models
│   └── case.py
├── routes
│   └── v1
│       ├── api_cases.py
│       └── api_test.py
├── services
└── templates`

Code organization:

- **Controllers:**

  Called from routes. Glue in application that are responsible for processing requests. Works by getting data in the `Models` using business logic from the `Services` and return results for the view. Should validate user input.

  Controller Actions: [Reference Guide](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/standard-controller-actions)

  - index
  - show
  - create
  - update
  - destroy

    - Plural file names: eg: `cases.py`
    - Plural class names: eg: `Cases`
- **Models:**

  Database interaction related code here. Responsible for data integrity.

  - Singular file name: eg: `case.py`
  - Singular class name: eg: `Case`
- **Routes:**

  Handles URI requests, these are BluePrints in Flask. Calls `Controllers`. Organized into a namespaced version for the api using `v1`. API related routes go within this directory.

  - Plural file names, with `api` prefix: eg: `api_cases.py`